# How different is training a factor graph with discriminative features?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, inference, graphical-model

Many of the people define graphical models with factors, each with 'conditional probability tables' (CPT) and perform inference on them.

But more realistic case is when you can't define full probability tables, and instead you define functions of features with some probabilities (as in discriminative models):

[image: 111]

[image: 222]

Suppose we have an algorithm for inference on factor graphs defined with CPT. Implementation-wise, can I just use the same algorithm for inference on the above log-linear model?